# Ansible task template with output_encoding: base64 throws unknown encoding

Tags: python, ansible

Following is the ansible task

```
- name: copy file
  template:
    src: app.properties.j2
    dest: "{{ installDir }}/app.properties"
    output_encoding: base64
```

While executing the above task, ansible throws the following error
`An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: LookupError: unknown encoding: base64` and the detailed stacktrace is

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 140, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 612, in _execute
    result = self._handler.run(task_vars=variables)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/action/template.py", line 187, in run
    f.write(to_bytes(resultant, encoding=output_encoding, errors='surrogate_or_strict'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/module_utils/_text.py", line 133, in to_bytes
    return obj.encode(encoding, errors)
LookupError: unknown encoding: base64
```

This is the output of ansible version command

```
ansible 2.7.7
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) [GCC 8.3.0]
```

All these libraries are packaged in dockerfile.  Please help / advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you find documentation suggesting that `base64` was a valid value for `output_encoding`?

The Ansible [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) say "It defaults to utf-8, but any encoding supported by python can be used.".

In Python, output encodings are provided by the `codecs` module, which is meant to control the conversion between byte strings and language specific characters. It supports things like `utf-8` and `latin1`, etc, but not `base64`.

If you want to `base64` encoding something in Ansible, use the `b64encode` filter.

You could do something like:

```
- name: render template to variable
  set_fact:
    template_value: "{{ lookup('template', 'app.properties.j2') }}"

- name: write base64 encoded file
  copy:
    dest: "{{ installDir }}/app.properties"
    content: "{{ template_value | b64encode }}"
```

Comment: Same task (with ``` base64 ``` is running with no errors on  the following ``` ansible 2.9.11
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/innsh@eur.ad.sag/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Jul 20 2020, 15:37:01) [GCC 7.5.0]
```